# Dispatch Custom Javascript Event wiith using the new api for CustomEvent

Tags: javascript

I have an issue where i am restricted by the version of phantomJS on the server.

When our headless tests run, Im unable to use CustomEvent api in javascript as Phantom does not understand it.

In browser the code works as exepcted:

```
var event = new CustomEvent("Interval", {
  detail: {
    type: 'foo',
    IntervalId: 1234,
  }
});

dispatchEvent(event);
```

I need to perform the same task, but by using an older method, pre CustomEvent. Is there a way to do this with the `detail` object intact?

Comment: Can't you use a polyfill? That said: I'd expect PhantomJS tp be lagging quite a bit these days--you should probably switch solutions because the situation is unlikely to improve unless you find one that's kept pace w/ JS over the past 2-3 years.

Comment: Yes I agree, its such an old version too, but thats outside of my control im afraid.

Comment: I'd recommend convincing whoever **is** in control that 2-3-year-old JS is insufficient and risky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what you need a polyfill for `CustomEvent`: https://gist.github.com/WebReflection/6693661

Comment: anyway I still recommend you to switch to another library which is faster and newer